# c# ssdt row edit & using where

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools

I want to edit the data in a rather large mssql table that is in a Windows Azure SQL Database. So, I try this by creating a query with a "where" clause, and then I expect to edit some cells by choosing them directly from the results pane.

I try to use Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools (last, 11.1.30618.1), VS 12. 
I found two modes: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UsOf.png — i can't edit cell's
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh1lc.png — i can't found my query to add where section

I ve tried another solution:
http://darrylbajaro.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/how-to-edit-ms-sql-records-with-filtering-on-sql-management-studio/
But since I'm using a Windows Azure SQL Database, it does not have the same options and so will not work (ssms 11.0.2100.60): https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0J7x.png

I d like something like heidli sql (I've used it many years for mysql), but for azure+mssql, maybe someone knows?

Comment: Dmitry, maybe you can edit your data by using an UPDATE statement.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @STLDeveloper thanks, yes, i can, but it's donkey work, also i can use mssql->excel->mssql, but it's bad to..

Comment: Could you use MS Access to link to the table and edit that way? I haven't tried editing a SQL Azure DB table yet so not sure of best way or if it's even possible that way.

Comment: @PeterSchott, really creative solution :) I'm trying to find a solution how to connect access. Unsuccessfully. If i find, i ll post it.

Comment: Does this help at all? http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2010/06/07/access-2010-and-sql-azure.aspx

Comment: @Dmitry I feel your pain. I posted something similar today (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770784/visual-studio-sql-server-design-and-inline-editing-features-missing). In my case I'm linking to a SQL Server 2012 DB, but no inline editting capability unlike with SQL 2008 DBs. Donkey work indeed!